# Extending abstract classes

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract

MyMath's constructor is supposed to call Homework's constructor, but super(); returns an error 'cannot find symbol'. It should not have any arguments.
Also, I am confused about how to call the method createAssignment using an arraylist, but I have to use it. Any advice?

### Homework

```
public abstract class Homework {
    private int pagesToRead;
    private String typeHomework;

    public Homework(int pages, String hw) {
        // initialise instance variables
        pagesToRead = 0;
        typeHomework = "none";
    }

    public abstract void createAssignment(int p);

    public int getPages() {
        return pagesToRead;
    }

    public void setPagesToRead(int p) {
        pagesToRead = p;
    }

    public String getTypeHomework() {
        return typeHomework;
    }

    public void setTypeHomework(String hw) {
        typeHomework = hw;
    }


}
```

### MyMath

```
public class MyMath extends Homework {

    private int pagesRead;
    private String typeHomework;

    public MyMath() {
        super();
    }

    public void createAssignment(int p) {
        setTypeHomework("Math");
        setPagesToRead(p);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return typeHomework + " - " + pagesRead;
    }
}

public class testHomework {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Homework> list = new ArrayList<Homework>();
        list.add(new MyMath(1));
        list.add(new MyJava(1));

        for (Homework s : list) {
            s.createAssignment();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't defined a no-arg constructor in the `Homework` class, so you can't call it.

Comment: The super class doesn't have a default constructor with no parameters.

Comment: Your TestHomework class has compile time errors. Where is MyJava defined? And you are not passing an integer to the create assignment method

Comment: I'm also a little unclear about what you mean by "call the method createAssignment using an arraylist".  The `createAssignment()` method takes an `int` as its argument, and the only `ArrayList` you've created is an `ArrayList<Homework>`.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I forgot to paste the MyJava class.

Comment: I am supposed to call on the createAssignment method through the for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Compiler error:**

Regarding the compiler error, you have to change the MyMath constractor to somthing like:

```
 public MyMath() {
        super(someInt, someString);
    }
```

Or, you can add a non-arg constructor to the Homework class:

```
 public Homework() {
        this(someInt,someString);
    }
```

You can learn about the `super()` keyword in the [Javadocs tutoriel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor,
>   the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument
>   constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a
>   no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object
>   does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass,
>   there is no problem.

**Code Suggestion:**

As there is many other issues in your question, i modified all your classes like below:

*Homework.java:*

```
public abstract class Homework {
    private int pagesToRead;
    private String typeHomework;

    {
        // initialise instance variables
        pagesToRead = 0;
        typeHomework = "none";
    }

    public Homework(int pages, String hw) {

        this.pagesToRead = pages;
        this.typeHomework = hw;

    }

    public abstract void createAssignment(int p);

    public int getPages() {
        return pagesToRead;
    }

    public void setPagesToRead(int p) {
        pagesToRead = p;
    }

    public String getTypeHomework() {
        return typeHomework;
    }

    public void setTypeHomework(String hw) {
        typeHomework = hw;
    }

}
```

*MyMath.java*

```
public class MyMath extends Homework {

    private int pagesRead;
    private String typeHomework;

    public MyMath(int pages, String hw) {
        super(pages,hw);
    }

    public void createAssignment(int p) {
        setTypeHomework("Math");
        setPagesToRead(p);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return typeHomework + " - " + pagesRead;
    }
}
```

*TestHomework.java:*

```
class TestHomework {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Homework> list = new ArrayList<Homework>();

        // will create a homework with type Math and one page to read
        list.add(new MyMath(1,"Math"));

        // Assuming MyJava is similar to MyMath
        list.add(new MyJava(1,"Java"));


        for (Homework s : list) {

            if (s instanceof MyMath) {
            // modify the number of pages to read for the Math homework
            s.createAssignment(3);
            } else if (s instanceof MyJava) {
            // modify the number of pages to read for the Java homework
            s.createAssignment(5);
            } else {
            s.createAssignment(7);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could I change it to super(p); ? This is what i am the most confused about.

Comment: yes, but we have to change it also in the Homewrok constractor like public Homework(int pages), is that what you want ?

Comment: Where did the three come from in s.createAssignment(3); ?

Comment: 3 is just an example, you can put any int number you want :)

Comment: So if I were to add more objects, like MyJava, how would i adjust that?

Comment: you need to implement that class in the same way you implemented MyMath then add it to your list like you did in your code

Comment: What would s.createAssignment(3);  look like then? I have to use a for each loop

Comment: @apsstudent i modified the code now, the numbers in createAssignement could be any numbers you want